# Folded stem on apples - does it have a name?

Tags: botany, trees, fruit

I have some Newton Wonder apple trees. One feature of the apples it bears is that the flesh around the stalk is occasionally elongated out of the calyx. Below is a picture that shows this on the near side.

[image: Newton Wonder]

Is there a specific name for this feature in apples?